# C# CCS PIC - Enhance equations processing

Tags: c#, performance, casting, pic

I'm using a PIC 18F2550 programmed with CCS to do several things. The root of my problem is that one of my interruptions handles an equation that I need to process often, and that controls several variables. This equation process involves typecasting, it has *int16*'s as input variables and it's result is an *int8* variable. This process takes too long and it slows down my other interruptions, causing several problems.

How can I speed up this function as much as possible but without hindering it's accuracy as much?

```
void dynamicControl(){
   refDelta = phRef - procSignal[0]; //all 3 are int16 variables.
   int16 prOffset = procSignal[1] - 500; //Their values will change on every iteration
   int16 _fixed(2) calcVar; //Tried using float and double here but with no success.
   if (refDelta < 0) {
      risePr = TRUE; dropPr = FALSE;
      calcVar = ((int16 _fixed(2))prOffset / 65.00) * (int16 _fixed(2))(4 - refDelta) + 1;
      nValPuls = (int8)calcVar;
   } else if(refDelta > 0){
      risePr = FALSE; dropPr = TRUE;
      nValPuls = (refDelta - 1);
   } else {
      risePr = dropPr = FALSE;
      nValPuls = 0x00;
   }
   if (refDelta < 10){
      calcVar = ((int16 _fixed(2))prOffset / 100.00) * (int16 _fixed(2))(5 - refDelta) * 0.70 + 18.00;
      pumpDutyLock = (int8)calcVar;
      if(pumpDutyLock > 30) pumpDutyLock = 30;
   } else { pumpDutyLock = 0x00; }

}
```

The 4 lines of code that slow down my code are the following. If I comment them all, the function runs at a good speed.

```
  calcVar = ((int16 _fixed(2))prOffset / 65.00) * (int16 _fixed(2))(4 - refDelta) + 1;
  nValPuls = (int8)calcVar;

  calcVar = ((int16 _fixed(2))prOffset / 100.00) * (int16 _fixed(2))(5 - refDelta) * 0.70 + 18.00;
  pumpDutyLock = (int8)calcVar;
```

I realize that typecasting takes a long time here, I've tried using *float* or *double* for *calcVar*, instead of *int16 _fixed(2)*, with no progress.

EDIT: After some further research I've found that, as stated by the comments, most of these operations take at least 50 us to complete, which means my problem cannot be solved by modifying the equation. I've resorted to transfering most of the calculations over to the PC side of the system.

Comment: What slows down the function? the calculation or the `(int8)` casting? What `int16 _fixed(2)` is?

Comment: Both, as the calculation involves casting. int16 _fixed(2) is a type of variable implemented by CCS, essentially a float with 2 digit decimal precision (i.e. 8.99). But using float or double would still work, as I've tried them, and both slow down anyway.

Comment: If casting is the issue and not the calculation itself I would use `floats` for all calculation and in the end instead of casting (int8) i would manually get the integer part of the float value. You need to know the standard the compiler uses to store 16bits floats.

Comment: Wouldn't that be essentially the same? Also, I've tried using only floats, disregarding the casting, and it still delays. Seems the compiler takes a long time for a simple division. I'll have to find a different approach.

Comment: Try to avoid all float calculations on such a small 8 Bit controller!

Comment: Appears that your function fails at design and implementation for a PIC18F2550, as the code executes in an interrupt then takes so long other interrupts are blocked from execution. The CCS compiler may have issues with all the explicit & implicit type casts between floats, _fixed(2) floats & integers, that with the floating point multiplies and divides kill performance on an 8-bit PIC. If you must have this calculation completed in minimum time & before any other interrupts can be processed the method must be redesigned. Using only integer math with powers of 2 for divisions may work.